how to make changes to shopify new upgraded checkout page
I want to make the price as 0 based on the tags(i.e free-gift) of a product in the new upgraded checkout page.how can I achieve this ? help me.I could not figure out anything till now. so I am asking the community. In the old checkout using the script I could make the prize as 0 but in the upgraded checkout the code does not reflect the changes added

You have to use shopify functions. Specifically cart transform functions.
